# Как вывести каждый элемент списка List<String> с новой строки?

Tags: java, массивы, list

В процессе выполнения упражнения напал *тупняк*. Необходимо что бы каждый элемент списка `List<String> hobby`, выводился в консоли с новой строки, именно из переопределённого метода `toString()` (условия задачи). На данный момент, хобби выводятся просто строкой с фигурными скобками. Как можно исправить, что бы всё получилось?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите имя: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Введите логин: ");
        String login = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Введите возраст: ");
        byte age = in.nextByte();
        System.out.print("Введите хобби через запятую: ");
        String hobby_1 = in.nextLine();
        String hobby_2 = in.nextLine();
        String[] hobbyArr = hobby_2.split(",");
        List<String> hobby = Arrays.asList(hobbyArr);

        User Admin = new User(name, login, age, hobby);
        System.out.print(Admin);
public class  User implements Serializable {

    public String name;
    public String login;
    public byte age;
    public List<String> hobby;

    public  User() {}

    public  User (String name, String login, byte age, List<String> hobby) {
       this.name = name;
       this.login = login;
       this.age = age;
       this.hobby =hobby;

        }
    public  String toString(){
        return "Пользователь: " + name + " c логином: " + login + ". Его возраст: " + age +
                ". Все хобби: " + hobby;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  String toString() {
        return "Пользователь: " + name + " c логином: " + login + ". Его возраст: " + age +
                ". Все хобби:\n" + hobby.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так))

```
   for(int i = 0; i<Admin.size(); i++){
       String j = Admin.get(i);
       System.out.println(j)
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]